# how better place back button?

Tags: buttons, css, back-button, html5

Our main goal is, to keep the ability to go back SOMEWHERE
but we don’t want it to be too prominent. Where should we put that button?

This is the link to the live page where this button called 'Ürün listesine geri dön' 
http://dev-front.sanalposentegrasyonu.com/#/checkout/2

[image]

Comment: Is all the page going back or only the right part (and the left part staying there after)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick, try to put the button in some intuitive place, but yet so it won't brake your page structure. Something like in the following image - the button is at the bottom-left corner. I don't know what it is said there(at that corner), but you got the point, I hope:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with a few options, as always. But since this is a *post hoc* solution, existing page structure needs to be preserved. If this were my project, I'd volunteer these two solutions:

**Solution 1:** No change, cheapest solution. Browsers and devices already have a back-button or some type of back function. Users will be familiar with this.

**Solution 2:** Back button to the right of *Melen Rafting*. Most users quickly realize they are in the wrong place and won't scroll to the bottom of the page or search for a back button. But if a back button is immediately present, they might use it.

[image]

This placement also won't disrupt page structure and will work well with your mobile styling.

[image]

Of course, use whatever icon or text or picture best represents your back function. I'm simply referring to its placement.

Hope it helps!