# Position and style of back button in web

Tags: buttons, web, back-button

After studying about the 'Back' button, I still can't decide on which best suited my case. I am designing an internal portal where the content varies in width.

[image]

Button position:

A.1

- Right side seems like a more common location for the buttons.
- In other pages, where there is the 'Back' and 'Next' button, it makes more sense that the next button is on the right side of the page.

A.2

- left side is good since the location of the button would stay regardless of width size of content.

[image]

Style:

B.1

- I also saw some platform that replaced their back button at the bottom with an arrow beside the page title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how better place back button?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/104844/how-better-place-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In short: Put the button at the top left of the form because it's:

- in a similar place to where most browsers put the browser back button
- most likely to be needed soon after the user lands on a page that looks wrong or if the user wants to check what they just entered
- probably not needed once the user fills out the form—if they fill out the form and click back, they will lose their answers

This approach clearly differentiates the back button from the primary button which should decrease the time it takes users to proceed. And it makes room for additional buttons when needed.

Check this article out for more information, background and research:
https://adamsilver.io/articles/where-to-put-buttons-on-forms/